# Has Constantine ever fought Hades?

Tags: dc, constantine

As we know that Hades exists in the DC comics and he is god of Hell and John Constantine is hellblazer have they ever come face to face in a fight? If not do they have different versions of hell for them?

Comment: I don't remember and I believe he exists in a separate universe than John.

Comment: *Hellblazer* was a comic in DC imprint - Vertigo and didn't need to worry about like anything in DC proper.

Comment: @Mithoron Constantine was a member of Justice League Dark, together with such people like Wonder Woman, so it is possible https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Dark_(Prime_Earth). It seems that "Hellblazer" has a new retcon, with younger John in modern times that is joined wioth the rest of DC. But even the old series was in the same univers (sort of - DC was trying to keep Constantine away from the other heroes for safety reasons) - i.e. there was a scene where someone asks, could John organise fight between Swamp Thing and Superman.

Comment: @Yasskier There were many new series with him, more or less unsuccessful afaik. Well, it's possible somewhere there's some story with Hades, or in film or series as he was in some lately. Originally his hellish enemies were First of Fallen and Nergal.